# How to group elements in xml layout for align in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, view, alignment

I have `TextView` and `ImageButton` in `xml` layout. And `ImageButton` is positioned right of `TextView` and I want group both to center them horizontally at screen. I use `RelativeLayout`.

What should I do?

Comment: what language/environment are you talking about? relevant tags are needed here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are developing an android application... If so this code can be used:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/headerText"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/hello_world"
           />

       <ImageButton
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
       </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

`android:layout_centerInParent="true"` will place items in the middle of the `RelativeLayout` parent
`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` will only center items horizontally. You can remove the one you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

An optimized approach, which doesn't use unnecessary layout nesting and reduces the View counts by incorporating the image inside the TextView:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The secret is the use of the compund drawable `android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"`.
To change it programmatically, use [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)